# UITableViewCell with 'Three column' Autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios9

I have a UITableViewCell with the following layout:

```
-----------------------------------
[Label1] [Label2         ][Button1]
[Label3] [Label4         ][Button2]
                          [Button3]
------------------------------------
```

I'd like to think of this as three columns, where [Label2] and [Label4] can have variable content, meaning the height of these labels can change. The height and width for [Label1], [Label3] and [Button1], [Button2] and [Button3] is fixed.

```
Column 1 - fixed width
[Label1]
[Label3]

Column 2 - variable width and height
[Label2]
[Label4]

Column 3 - fixed width and height
[Button1]
[Button2]
[Button3]
```

What is the optimal way of using Autolayout to achieve this layout?

Answer (score 0):

Label 1 constrained to left and top of cell's content view with fixed width and height.

Label 3 constrained to left of cell's content view with fixed width and height.

Button 1,2,3 constrained to right of cell's content view and fixed width and height. Button 1 and 2 vertically centered to Label 1 and Label 3 respectively.

Label 2 have leading constrained to Label 1 and trailing constrained to Button 1. It's top is constrained to Label 1 and bottom should be constrained to top of label 3.

Label 4 have leading constrained to Label 3 and trailing constrained to Button 2. It's top is constrained to Label 3 and bottom should be constrained to top of button 3.

Button 3 bottom constrained to bottom of your cell's content view.

Label 2 and Label 4 should be set to have 0 number of lines.

You may also want to set spacing between label 1 - label 3 and button 2 - button 3 to be greater than or equal to 8, in case there is no text in label 2 and label 4, they want collapse entire cell,

Your table view should use self re-sizing cells (`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`).

Comment: Label 2 bottom should be constrained to top of label 3 ?